# How does one properly close a captain proto struct to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: python, capnproto

I think I have memory issues and I want to close the file I've read using pycapnp. How is the best way to do this? Is doing:

```
    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> DagNode:
        # gets the file idx for the value we want
        file_idx = self.get_file_index(idx)
        file_name = self.list_files_current_split[file_idx]
        f = open(file_name)
        capnp_file = dag_api_capnp.Dag.read_packed(f, traversal_limit_in_words=2 ** 64 - 1)
        # do stuff with it
        node = DagNode(capnp_file.field1)
        # close both files
        capnp_file.finish()
        f.close()
        return node
```

in my scenario I have a data set saved in the captian proto format and I want to close the captain proto file after I've extracted the information I need from it (so to avoid memory issues and not waste space!). What is the proper way to do this, the

`.finish()`

method guaranteed to do this? I don't have to call the garbage collector...right?

Thanks in advance!

reference:

- http://capnproto.github.io/pycapnp/capnp.html#capnp._DynamicResizableListBuilder.finish
- https://github.com/capnproto/pycapnp/issues/245
- https://github.com/capnproto/pycapnp/issues/251

Comment: Why do you think you have memory issues?  What are the symptoms?  A file does not use any memory.  You are reading the contents into `capnp_file`, and you pass that to `DagNode`, which you return.  If `DagNode` keeps a reference, then the memory will stick around even after you're through with it.  How large is the data?

Comment: Do you try with a context manager?

Comment: @FrancoMorero I don't think one can do a context manager with captain proto. But I have to admit it didn't occur to me. Will try it.

Comment: @TimRoberts the data set is very large. Gigabytes. But the memory profiler used to keep increasing until the OS killed my job. That is why I am now passing the field I need directly instead of the file. Why wouldn't a file take memory? Doesn't the captain proto read load the contents to the variable `capnp_file `? Perhaps a normal python file is just a pointer to a file but based on my memory issues I had I'd assume I wasn't closing the contents of `capnp_file ` properly but i need to wait  a couple of hours to do the preprocessing to test the new code. Will report what happened.

Comment: The main reason I asked my question is because after I am done with the captain proto file I that I loaded into memory into `capnp_file` variable, I want to close it (like I'd do in python with `f.close()`). That is what I am hoping to do to avoid the previous bug I had but perhaps passing the fields isntead will fix my bug.

Comment: Yes, `capnp_file` uses memory, because you copied the contents of the file there.  But the file object itself doesn't take memory.  It just a file handle and a pointer to the current location.  Is there a way to process the file in chunks?

Comment: @TimRoberts hmmm are you suggesting that this might be the line that is causing the error? `dag_api_capnp.Dag.read_packed(dependency_file, traversal_limit_in_words=2 ** 64 - 1)` because of the giant traversal limit `traversal_limit_in_words=2 ** 64 - 1`?

Comment: Of course it is. None of the other lines consume any memory.  That line will read your whole file into memory and construct a DAG out of it.  I don't know how `traversal_limit` affects that, but you realize you don't actually have 2^64 bytes of virtual memory available, right?  The theoretical limit on Windows is 2^43, but the practical limit is much lower because of the page table size.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried python memory-mapped file support?
[mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)
It works much like os handling huge swap files. It's extremely fast and efficient. use readBytes to collect chunks of data (guess it's traversal_limit_in_words ?)

In short, all data needed is available at right time in your program memory space and further loading of data is taken care by mmap.

hope this helps!